# Comma after prepositional phrase

Tags: grammar, punctuation

There seems to be a general rule that a prepositional phrase of five or more words should be followed by a comma. But is this rule always correct? The second of these two sentences looks better to me:

> For example, if you are using a lathe, then after completing the first two steps, you should check the spindle.
>
> For example, if you are using a lathe, then after completing the first two steps you should check the spindle.